# php troubles with coding variables

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to echo certain values if the variable $cardtype ==

```
     $paymentmethod = if( $cardtype == 'visa' ) echo 'VSA'; 
elseif ( $cardtype == 'mastercard' ) echo 'MSC'; 
elseif ( $cardtype == 'mastercard' ) echo 'MSC'; 
elseif ( $cardtype == 'maestro' ) echo 'MAE'; 
elseif ( $cardtype== 'amex' ) echo 'AMX';
```

How would I do this???

Comment: a couple of line breaks would make the code a lot more readable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$types = array( 'visa' => 'VSA', 'mastercard' => 'MSC', 
                'maestro' => 'MAE', 'amex' => 'AMX' );

echo ( isset( $types[ $cardtype ] ) ) ? $types[ $cardtype ] : 'Wrong card type';
```

Comment: Using `isset` is shorter and faster than `array_key_exists`. It also has a more natural syntax.

Comment: Careful guys, there's a drive-by downvoter in the house. Make sure your shotguns are loaded.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in acceptance. Yes this has answered my question thanks Jacob

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function containing a switch statement for this:

```
function GetPaymentMethod( $cardtype )
{
    switch( $cardtype )
    {
    case 'visa':
      return 'VSA';
    case 'mastercard':
      return 'MSC';
    case 'maestro':
      return 'MAE';
    case 'amex':
      return 'AMX';
    default:
      return '<Invalid card type>';
    }
}
```

Test:

```
echo GetPaymentMethod( 'visa' ); // VSA
```

Comment: You *could*, but it can be done much more concisely with an associative array

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
switch($cardtype) {
 case 'visa':
  echo 'VSA';
  break;
 case 'mastercard':
  echo 'MSC';
  break;
}
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

for your own code, you have to just remove strange `$paymentmethod =` from the beginning.

```
if( $cardtype == 'visa' ) echo 'VSA';  
elseif ( $cardtype == 'mastercard' ) echo 'MSC'; 
elseif ( $cardtype == 'maestro' ) echo 'MAE'; 
elseif ( $cardtype== 'amex' ) echo 'AMX';
```

it will work too.