# PHP Get variable to equal value of switch

Tags: php, variables, switch-statement

I am trying to get a variable on my page to equal the result of a switch I have.

This is the code:

```
$payment_method = switch ($cardtype) {
case "visa" : echo "VSA"; break;
case "mastercard" : echo "MSC"; break;
case "maestro" : echo "MAE"; break;
case "amex" : echo "AMX" ; break;
default : echo "Please specify a payment method!"; break;
};
```

How can I get $payment_method to equal the result of this????

So far I recieve an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SWITCH in /var/www/account/credits/moneybookers/process.php on line 65
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php troubles with coding variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875567/php-troubles-with-coding-variables)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: lol, the same question from the same user %-)

Comment: Not quite the same. He's asking for the variable assignment now, not echo. But that's why all these codes a bad: he's just copy/baste it without understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should assign the value *within* the switch:

```
switch ($cardtype) {
    case "visa":
        $payment_method = "VSA";
    break;
    case "mastercard":
        $payment_method = "MSC";
    break;
    case "maestro":
        $payment_method = "MAE";
    break;
    case "amex":
        $payment_method = "AMX";
    break;
    default:
        echo "Please specify a payment method!";
    break;
};
```

Answer (score 16):

do in this way:

```
$types = array('visa' => 'VSA', 'mastercard' => 'MSC', 'maestro' => 'MAE', 'amex' => 'AMX');
if (isset($types[$cardtype])) {
    $payment_method = $types[$cardtype];
} else {
    echo 'Please specify a payment method!';
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use arrays!

```
$types = array("visa"       => "VSA",
               "mastercard" => "MSC",
               "maestro"    => "MAE",
               "amex"       => "AMX");

$type = @$types[$cardtype] or echo "Please specify a payment method!";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the  `switch` construct this way. You would have to assign `$payment_method` within the `case` parts.

In your case, seeing as you're `echo` ing anyway, you can just remove `$payment_method =` and it should work.

What would be much, much easier, though, is putting all the stuff into an array:

```
$payment_methods = array(
  "visa" => "VSA",
  "mastercard" => "MSC",
  "maestro" => "MAE",
  "amex" => "AMX"
);

if (!array_key_exists($cardtype, $payment_methods))
 echo "Please specify a payment method!";
else
 echo "Your method: ".$payment_methods[$cardtype];
```

Answer (score 3):

For your *application*, an associative array will be the best solution. To answer your *question* however, you can build your own switch/case out of ? operators

```
var card  = 'amex'; //however you retrieve that value

var method = card == 'visa' ? 'VSA' : card == 'mastercard' ? 'MSC' : card == 'maestro' ? 'MAE' : card == 'amex' : 'AMX' : null;  //default value is null

//  store error msgs elsewhere in the code, to ease translation/alteration
var errs = {
 'ENG', {'Please specify a payment method', '...', '...', '...'},
 'ESP', {'Favor, indique la forma de pago', '...', '...', '...'},
 'DEU', {'Bitte geben Sie eine Zahlungsmethode', '...','...','...'}
}

//  alert the appropriate error message, in the current language

var currentLang = 0; //however you set that value
if(!method) alert(errs[currentLang][0]);
```

Comment: you shouldn't use the ternary operator in such a way. Readibility is paramount and in this case a switch is the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
$payment_method = '';

switch ($cardtype) {
  case "visa" : $payment_method = "VSA"; break;
  case "mastercard" : $payment_method = "MSC"; break;
  case "maestro" : $payment_method = "MAE"; break;
  case "amex" : $payment_method = "AMX" ; break;
}

if (strlen($payment_method))
{
  echo $payment_method;
}
else
{
  echo "Please specify a payment method!";
}
```

Comment: default : $payment_method = "Please specify a payment method!"; // with this implementation it will be impossible to get is payment method valid or not.

Comment: @zerkms: right, fixed main, please consider your down vote. Thanks

Comment: @Wed Logic: fixed ;-) btw, he will get notice with this code, when $cardtype is invalid

Comment: @zerkms: What he would notice, could not get you?

Comment: now - nothing. i have commented the revision #2 without if(strlen()), which you have added later ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `match` statement.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php

Example:

```php
$message = match ($statusCode) {
    200, 300 => null,
    400 => 'not found',
    500 => 'server error',
    default => 'unknown status code',
};
```

Also: https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-match-or-switch

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your code (like if you have very long switch), you can use [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

```
<?php
ob_start();
switch ($cardtype) {
case "visa" : echo "VSA"; break;
case "mastercard" : echo "MSC"; break;
case "maestro" : echo "MAE"; break;
case "amex" : echo "AMX" ; break;
default : echo "Please specify a payment method!"; break;
};
$payment_method = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

`ob_start()` will start output buffering (which will also stop output) and `ob_get_clean()` will end it, returning everything echoed while ob running.

So, for example, if `$cardtype` is visa, $payment_method will equal to VSA.

Hope it helps.

> **Note:** This might not be a good solution, if possible, please, use solution from any other answer. Pekka's answer is really good one, try his.